# JAX-RS Jersey JAX-B not binding JSON field correctly based on Generic type

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am calling a REST based JAX-RS web service from a Javascript client sending a JSON payload and Jersey is unable to convert the appropriate type used in my class hierarchy, I have:

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class MyVO extends BaseVO<Integer> {
 // ... fields
}
```

and

```
public abstract class BaseVO<ID extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private ID id;

    public ID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
  // other methods ...
}
```

The JSON payload is being correctly sent on the client side with the appropriate id field in place

```
{"type":"myVO","id":4,"name":"myVO"}
```

but when it gets to the server side Jersey is incorrectly extracting the payload field as a String and not converting it to an Integer as it should be based on it's actual ID type. During runtime the actual ID class for id field of MyVO is String and not Integer, when I try to cast it manually I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

is it possible to have JAX-RS automatically discover the correct type of the field based on the given hierarchy ?

Comment: Might not be the issue, but you've declared the `id` as private in `BaseVO` and want to inject the id-field, which is not accessible in `MyVO`. Have you tried to set it as protected instead of private in `BaseVO`? Some frameworks will set values into fields and ignoring setters. As generics are replaced with the concrete type at compile-time, the generic should not be the issue IMO.

Comment: I tried changing it to protected but I get the same error